# Hugo deploy and delete not necessary files

Tags: github, deployment, gulp, web-deployment, hugo

I'm developing a new Hugo site and in this case I thought to create also a template so.I can use for future site. 
Well in the template there are tons of vendor files and library because depending of the pages that the site will implement these library will be used. The problem is on the deploy. For example I use Line icons library that has a lot of .png files. (For example 200 files).
Well in the template I put all the files but could happen that in the site that implement this template I use only five icons. Is there a way that look around the final HTML and the usage of the icons and delete in the public folder the not necessary files?

Answer (score 0):

Not directly.

You would need to add an utility script to your template, in order for any user implementing said template to be able to call this script on demand.

That script should then be able to:

- analyze the HTML files generated in `public_html`
- cleanup the icons accordingly

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. Any idea in which language / technology write this script? How and when they have to call this script? Also a little example will be much than appreciated

Comment: @pinguinone the language should be one which does not require any runtime dependencies on the client side: Go (https://golang.org) would generate an executable without dependencies. Since Hugo itself is written in Go, there are plenty of examples in its own source code (https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo)